# How do I pick a good value of num_epochs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, cross-validation, loss-functions, recurrent-neural-network

I'm running a program that uses an RNN to build a language model of some sample text: https://github.com/crazydonkey200/tensorflow-char-rnn When training it, I currently use the default value of `num_epochs` (50). Passing `--verbose 1` to the program, I notice that the perplexity seems to stop decreasing at around 25 or 30 epochs, and since perplexity is just `exp(train_loss)` this means that the training loss is stabilizing as well.

Is it a good idea to limit the number of epochs to the point where the training loss stops decreasing significantly? I assume that means the model isn't getting any better from extra training, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few schools of thought on this topic.

1. Continue training until training loss stops decreasing, then stop. This can be as simple as squinting at a graph and making a judgement call, or as sophisticated as [statistically measuring whether loss is decreasing or not](http://blog.dlib.net/2018/02/automatic-learning-rate-scheduling-that.html).
2. Continue training until loss stops decreasing (as in **1**), then reduce the learning rate (say, by cutting it in half). The logic here is that some models do better with larger learning rates early on, but smaller learning rates later.
3. Use some function, like a very slow exponential decay, or a monotonic decreasing sigmoidal function, to slightly decrease the learning rate at each iteration.
4. [Super-convergence evangelists have their own, ornate methods](http://www.fast.ai/2018/07/02/adam-weight-decay/).